# How to apply the right permission "read" on a folder?

Tags: java, windows, file

How to apply the right permission "read" on a folder?

Hello,

Please, how can we apply the right permission "read" on a folder in a java class on Windows, and how can we know if we have the right to "read" on a folder or not?
"read" of course

I tested with canRead() and setReadable(true) provided by the "File" class of "io" java, but it's still not working!

the canRead() method always returns true even if you have no right to "Read" on the folder.

the setReadable(true) method does not apply the right "read" on the folder

```
import java.io.File;

public class TestTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("D:/Test");
    if(f.canRead())
        System.out.println("OK => "+f.setWritable(true));
    else
        System.out.println("KO");
}
}
```

Are there solutions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In Windows, the best way to find out whether you can read a file is to try to read it and see whether you get an error.  Trying to work it out in advance is neither straightforward nor reliable.  This is partly because the permissions model is complicated, and partly because that's not the only thing that could be blocking access to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new NIO.2 File API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html